# Unable to install app when app sdk version is 31 android 12

Tags: android, kotlin

Facing problem in installing app when updating target sdk of my current application to Android 12(sdk 31) ? I have added exported flags in tags where i declared intent-filters
in manifest but still not able to fix the issue.

Comment: What's the exact issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @benyuss when targeting sdk 12 in android project , I am unable to install build in android phone with android version 12  .  I have already added "exported" flags in intent -filters in manifest file but still it  throwing error saying third party libraries manifest have intent filters which doesn't have "exported" flag set.

Comment: @NiteshChauhan alright but what's the exact error message?